# symfony test app.user is null in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I use app.user in twig. When I write a test, I have a user logged in, and it works fine in a controller. But in twig, when accessing app.user, it is null.

Here is how I log the user in the test unit:

```
    $user = new User;
    $user->setRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
    $user->setUsername('admin');
    $firewallContext = 'main';
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken(serialize($user), null, $firewallContext, array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
    $session->set('_security_'.$firewallContext, serialize($token));
    $session->save();

    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
```

What am I missing to get it to work in twig?

Comment: copy the full function of your controller please... There is no render in this code.

Comment: This is the part of the controller where the render is. The code above stands in the test unit. `code` return $this->render('admin/listeutilisateurs.html.twig', array(
          'users'=>$Users,
          'roles'=>$tab,
          'equipes'=>$equipes,
        )); `code`

Comment: in your controller, you pass `users` as parameters to your twig view, not `app`. So doing `app.user` won't works. `app` isn't defined, thus doesn't exists in tour twig view.

Comment: No, the app variable does exist in twig as global variable, and it's working. It's only in the test that this variable (app.user) is null.

Comment: The logged user is not set in to session, because the serialize() is not counting all the necessary fields.

Comment: ref: https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security/entity_provider.html#security-serialize-equatable

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (logging in properly) what solved it finally for me was to change the way I log in, this is my authorized client and you could adapt it to your purpose. (symfony version: 2.8)

```
private function createAuthorizedClient() 
{
      $client = static::createClient();
      $container = static::$kernel->getContainer();
      $session = $container->get('session');
      $token = new UsernamePasswordToken('john.doe', null, 'main', array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
      $session->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
      $session->save();
      $client->getCookieJar()->set(new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId()));
      return $client;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's roughly the same as what I have, but I tried it anyway. And same result, it works fine in a controller, but not in twig for the app.user.

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell you how to setup Twig in the test environment to provide `app.user`, but i have made a workaround to almost get the same functionality.

**In a nutshell:**

- Create a Twig extension to get the current user in a Twig template (like `get_user()`).
- `get_user()`: It checks if it runs in APP_ENV==test. If yes, than it gets the User instance from an `UsernamePasswordToken` instance, otherwise it returns the stored user from the current Twig `Environment` instance.

The following code should run out of the box for Symfony 4.3+, but its untested.

---

### App/TwigExtensions/SecurityExtension.php

The following extension provides `get_user()` inside a Twig template.

```php
<?php

namespace App\TwigExtension;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Twig\Environment;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class SecurityExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    protected $currentUser;
    protected $session;
    protected $twigEnvironment;

    public function __construct(
        Environment $twigEnvironment,
        SessionInterface $session
    ) {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->twigEnvironment = $twigEnvironment;
    }

    public function getUser(): User
    {
        if (null !== $this->currentUser) {
            return $this->currentUser;
        }

        /*
         * if env == test
         */
        if ('test' == $_SERVER['APP_ENV']) {
            $token = \unserialize($this->session->get('_security_main'));
            if ($token instanceof UsernamePasswordToken && true === $token->isAuthenticated()) {
                $this->currentUser = $token->getUser();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * normal way
             */
            $this->currentUser = $this->twigEnvironment->getGlobals()['app']->getToken()->getUser();
        }

        return $this->currentUser;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('get_user', [$this, 'getUser']),
        ];
    }
}
```

### Test environment

In the following a complete test example how to call a controller action, which uses Twig behind.

```php
<?php

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\KernelBrowser;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

class OrderControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testEdit(): void
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $user = new User();
        // ... adapt it if you want

        $this->authenticateClientInstance($client, $user);

        // make the request
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/admin/order/');

        $response = $client->getResponse();

        // check the response
        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
    }

    protected function authenticateClientInstance(KernelBrowser $client, User $user): void
    {
        $session = $client->getContainer()->get('session');

        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', ['ROLE_USER']);
        $session->set('_security_main', \serialize($token));
        $session->save();

        $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
        $client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
    }
}
```

### Access via Twig

For instance:

```
{% set user = get_user() %}
```

---

### Summary

The solution is considered not the best way. The problem is, that you are required to use many Symfony components, which may not be suited to be used from non-Symfony components. You may also run into problems, if they change the API.

I secured this approach with further tests, to ensure it is working. You should also do that, in case Symfony 5.0+ breaks things.

Comment: Whould the downvoter be so kind and respond with a reason?